Looking for a cartoon TV series with kids riding motorbikes in a desert-like area
I'm looking for a kids cartoon TV series and can't remember the name of it.
Don't remember much about it either, just some glimpses:

there was a group of kids or teenagers that ride on motorbikes and monster truck like cars
it all takes place in a "desert" area, reminds me of those Texas/New Mexico roads like this:



there was a diner or restaurant that was probably the only building that appeared in that desert place
the characters hang out at that diner/restaurant
I think the characters take part in races of some sort and that's the main plot of the series (but it's a maybe cause I might be confusing that part with some other show) 
I think the characters' design was similar to Rugrats
The show is from 90's or early 2000's, American. I saw it on tv on some kids channel so Cartoon Network/Fox Kids etc.

I don't remember anything else. I know this is not much but maybe someone recognises it?

Sounds like 'Hot Wheels Battle Force 5'.

Maybe "Rocket Power" on Nickelodeon.
They did a lot of sports including racing in dessert places in some episodes. But the diner they hung out was the sea shack somewhere at the pier. And they did a lot of races and stuff.
